# Inject a Groovy Closure into Expando that acts as Property

Tags: groovy, closures, expando

I have a class that extends Expando and gets injected with dynamic properties.

```
class Dynamo extends Expando {
}

Dynamo dynamic = [ firstName: 'bob', lastName: 'dobbs' ]
```

I'd like to create a dynamic property *fullName* that evaluates to *"$lastName, $firstName"*.

While it sort of does work to do this:

```
dynamic.fullName = { "$lastName, $fullName" }
```

It requires an call() or implicit call with () to return the string, otherwise it just gives the closure toString()

```
assert dynamic.fullName() == 'dobbs, bob'
```

**Passes**

But

```
assert dynamic.fullName == 'dobbs, bob'
```

**Fails** because that evaluates to the toString of the closure

I can always do this

```
Dynamo dynamic = [ firstName: 'bob', lastName: 'dobbs', fullName: 'dobbs, bob' ]
```

But that ain't DRY...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For parameterless methods, Groovy needs parenthesis. I can think of two solutions:

**Solution 1:** Metaclass the getter `getFullName`:

```
Dynamo dynamo = [ firstName: 'bob', lastName: 'dobbs' ]

dynamo.metaClass.getFullName = { "$lastName, $firstName" }

assert dynamo.fullName == 'dobbs, bob'
```

---

**Solution 2:** Hook into the property getters with `getProperty`:

```
Dynamo dyn2 = [ firstName: 'john', lastName: 'doe' ]
dyn2.metaClass.getProperty = { String property ->
    if (property == "fullName") { 
        "${delegate.lastName}, ${delegate.firstName}" 
    } 
}

assert dyn2.fullName == 'doe, john'
```

Comment: I thought I'd run into an issue with the metaclassing when another Dynamo has a "fullName" defined a true property. `Dynamo dyn3 = [ fullName: 'Anonymous' ]` but the Expando resolves the mapped property  before the metaclassed getFullName so it's **all good** -> Still wonder if there is way to do this with a lazy eval GString that could be just another attribute, but this might work just fine.